# Check SQL statements within PHP for bad words such as DROP or DELETE

Tags: php, sql, regex, preg-match

I would like to allow some admins to manually enter SQL statements in a textfield (to get statistic data etc.). On the database layer, I protected the data by creating a user which can only select but not update/delete etc.

I would like to add a second security by checking the inserted SQL for bad words such as `DROP`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`. I figured out how to do that with preg_match but I would love to have a smart script which can distiguish between a `DROP` and something like `WHERE name = 'DROP 1'`

**EDIT: I would like to log if an admin tries to uses such statements. That's why I need this second level security check. This is for clarification.**

Does anyone know a code snipped which fits this example?

Thanks!!

Comment: The more I look at this the more it seems like what your doing is just not a good idea. It looks like you're giving SQL to your end users then wishing to surreptitiously apply checking on that to make sure they are not trying to abuse the system.  Wouldn't you be better just using some sort of user query tool and sidestepping the whole issue?

Comment: Marc, please see my updated solution for a more solid approach to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for something as complex as SQL.

I'd start by looking at what SQL parsers are available for PHP, then use one of those to parse and analyze the SQL statements being used.

Try one of these:

http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser

http://sourceforge.net/projects/osqlp/

Answer (score 10):

#### New Response

Since you updated your question to clarify what you're looking for, I wanted to offer a different solution. Don't worry about what the user is submitting as a query, again, MySQL will spit back an error if they don't have sufficient privs to do something.

Capture that error with `mysql_error()`, and the error number with `mysql_errno()`. If the error message says **"DROP command denied..."** or the error number is **1142** then you know they tried being naughty. Looking for terms within this error is better than looking for terms in their query, as you rightly pointed out that their query can legitimately use the bad words.

#### Original Response

If your user can only `SELECT`, then they cannot `DROP` or `DELETE`. Looking for these words doesn't add any more security to the mix since the database will reject any queries that aren't explicitly allowed for that given user.

Comment: Good point about the basic question of whether a PHP check would even be needed to provide the security Marc wants.

Comment: Jonathan. Your solution does not at all solve my problem. I would like to check for those words and log if someone tried to do that (more security). So please do not think about the security issue.. my question was about the preg_match algorithm...

thanks

Comment: @Marc, You should update your question to clarify that you are looking for users attempting malicious actions, and not looking for a second level of security for the SQL statements. Based on the current wording of your question, Jonathan's answer is correct.

Comment: Ok. I edited the question. Did not know that stackoverflow has such a justify-your-question mindset..

Comment: @Marc, it's not justification, it's clarification. Most SO users, when they see someone about to do something "wrong" (for lack of a better word), will try to steer them in the right direction. That's why it's important to clearly post what your intended goal is.

Comment: It's more of a "clarify your question so that you can get useful answers" mindset. Most people would be happy to give you the answers you want if you ask the question in a way that makes sense to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the wrong place to put this level of security in.  So long as you have set the database up so the only have SELECT privileges then they cannot change the data in any way.  However is you give them any privileges that can change data then no amount of semantic checking on SQL statements will give you security.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create the commands for the stats data and allow the admins to call those commands? Isn't that easier?

Not saying the admins will do harm intentionally but it could happen!